# multiple angular application in single webpack config

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-aot, aot

i have project with many standelone angular application on it. Typical user case can be :

- admin.ts
- front.ts
- dashboard.ts

Where each are angular app. To manage that, i have actually single `webpack.config.js` where i do all packaging stuff.

The issue come when i want to add AoT compilation. For that i use [@ngtools/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack) where unfortunatly we have to hardcoded on our webpack configuration the entrypoint path like this :

```
  plugins: [
    new AngularCompilerPlugin({
      tsConfigPath: 'path/to/tsconfig.json',
      entryModule: 'path/to/app.module#AppModule',
      sourceMap: true
    })
  ]
```

as you [can see here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12107) on the angular-cli issue tracker, they not have any plan to handle multiple entry modules.

Have you any magic trick to play around this limitation and still keep single compilation process ?

[proof of concept is available on my github](https://github.com/yanis-git/multiple-angular-app)

Comment: Dear @yanis-git did you find the magic trick?

Comment: i have found a way to play around @Diego if you have look on my repository, you will have runnable PoC where i boostrap different webpack configuration base on parameter. if you want i can improve my readme to detail step by step.

Comment: No need to. I got it, it's perfectly clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking out [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack)

It extends [@angular-devkit/build-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular) but allows you to modify the webpack config. Allowing you to add other entry points, etc. It has fairly good documentation on how set it up.

Comment: Thanks you @Josh for your answer. I have already try this approch but i am facing design issue when i try to have AOT support. As you can see on my post, Angular need `AngularCompilerPlugin` object which provide entryModule. Plugins webpack section are shared for all webpack entrypoints.